# Apache commons StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\") returns ""

Tags: java, stringescapeutils

The following code:

```
final String INVALID_ESCAPE="\\";
System.out.println(String.format("'%s' -> '%s'", INVALID_ESCAPE, 
    StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(INVALID_ESCAPE)));
```

... produces:

```
'\' -> ''
```

on the console. Since `'\'` is not a valid escape I would expect an Exception at runtime. Am I missing anything?

UPDATE:
filled a bug(?) report in [Apache jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-885)

Comment: I would suggest you either file a bug at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG or post to the mailing list. Somebody should soon be able to inform you what the intended purpose of the method is and whether you've discovered a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.java?revision=1467206&view=markup):

```
// TODO: throw "illegal character: \92" as an Exception if a \ on the end of the Java (as per the compiler)?
```

Send a patch ;-)